# Is there an efficient way to get elements from one index to another index in a collection without changing it to an ArrayList?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to implement pagination within a java/spring boot app on a Collection that is returned from a function. I want to get pages that are ordered by each elements "startTime". So if the user asks for page 2 and each page has 10 items in it, then I would want to give the user the items with the top 10-20 most recent start times. I've since tried two approaches:
a) Converting the returned collection into an array and then using IntStream on it to get elements from one index to another.

```
final exampleClass[] example = exampleCollection.toArray(new exampleClass[0]);
Collection<exampleClass> examplePage = IntStream.range(start, end)
    ...
```

b) Converting the returned collection into an ArrayList and then using Pageable/PageRequest to create a new page from that ArrayList.

The problem is that these seem very inefficient since I first have to change the Collection to an ArrayList or array and then operate on it. I would like to know if there are more efficient ways to turn collections into structures that I can iterate on using indices so that I can implement pagination. Or, if there are some Spring functions for creating pages that don't require non-Collection parameters. However, I can't find any Spring functions for creating pages that do.

Also, is there any difference in runtime between

```
List<exampleClass> x = new ArrayList<>(exampleCollection);
```

and

```
 List<exampleClass> x = (List<exampleClass>)exampleCollection;
```

Comment: `subList` could be an option. Or just looping and adding to your new collection (not pretty, but it does the job. Implement it in a method to hide the ugliness)

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention this in my question (first question on stackoverflow) but I want to get pages that are ordered by each elements "startTime". So if the user asks for page 2 and each page has 10 items in it, then I would want to give the user the items with the top 10-20 most recent start times. If that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to know if there are more efficient ways to turn collections into structures that I can iterate on using indices

The only efficient way is to check by `instanceof` if your collection is indeed a `List`.  If it is, then you can cast it, and simply use e.g. `sublist(start, stop)` to produce your paginated result.

Please note that accessing an element by its index might not be efficient either. In a `LinkedList`, accessing an element is a O(N) operation, so accesing M elements by index produces a O(M*N) operation, whereas using `sublist()` is a O(M+N) operation.

There is a specialization of the `List` interface that is used to mark lists that are fast at being accessed by index, and that is : `RandomAccess`, you may or may not want to check on that to decide on the best strategy.

> Also, is there any difference in runtime between
>
> List x = new ArrayList<>(exampleCollection);
>
> and
>
> ```
> List<exampleClass> x = (List<exampleClass>)exampleCollection;
> ```

There absolutely is.

The second is a cast, and has virtually no cost. Just beware that `x` and `exampleCollection` are one and the same object (modifying one is the same as modifying the other). Obviously, a cast may fail with a ClassCastException if `exampleCollection` is not actually a list.

The first performs a copy, which has a cost in both CPU (traversal of `exampleCollection`) and memory (allocating an array of the collection's size). Both are pretty low for small collections, but your mileage may vary.

In this copy case, modifying one collection does nothing to the other, you get a copy.

Comment: So for the second cast, it's safe to assume that it's constant time? I learned this a while ago but it's a little fuzzy to me now. I can't think of how copying a collection to another collection could be done in constant time.

Comment: It is constant time, and the reason why is that a cast is NOT a copy. It's "just a way to make the compiler know of something". Seeing it is a compiler thing, it has no cost at runtime (except that the Java runtime wil actually check at runtime if the cast is correct, for safety reason, which is a tiny tiny cost compared to a copy). And the first solution is not a cast, it as a constructor call, of the class ArrayList, which performs a copy. So there is no "second cast". THere is a copy, and a single cast.

Comment: I just have one more quick question. Are the functions on collections, such as toList() or toArray(), also constant time?

Comment: Everythin that involves iterating the collection will be at least O(N). You will only have constant time if the call is a no-op (one can imagine that calling to list on a collection that is actually already a list is a no-op). So generally speaking : not constant time.

Answer (score 0):

A collection does not have to have consistent iteration order: if you call `iterator()` twice you may get two different sequences. Converting the collection into an array or a list is the best solution.

As for the second question: This line of code:

```
List<exampleClass> x = new ArrayList<>(exampleCollection);
```

creates a new ArrayList, which is a *shallow copy* of the original collection. That is, it contains pointers to the same objects as the original collection, but the list itself is new and you could for example sort the list, or add or remove items, without affecting the original collection. Compared to:

```
List<exampleClass> x = (List<exampleClass>)exampleCollection;
```

Assuming `exampleCollection` is actually a List, this gives you a pointer to that list with a new data type. If you make changes like sort or add or remove items, you will see these modifications in `exampleCollection`. On the other hand if `exampleCollection` is not a List, you will get a run-time error (ClassCastException).